# C Dir Scanning Entering Infinite Loop

Tags: c

```
int ScanDirectories(const char *dirname, struct images *imagesHeadPtr, struct filesToParse *filesHeadPtr)
{
    // scan the directory and store the entries in a buffer 


DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
int jpgs = 0, pngs = 0;
int totalFiles = 0;
int filesToScan = 0;
char name[256];
char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char));

if((dir = opendir(dirname)) == NULL)
{
    perror("Unable to open directory");
    DisplayFolderNotFound();
    return(0);
}

while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(name, ent->d_name);
    strncpy(tmp, name, 1);
    if(strcmp(tmp, ".") == 0)   //Not valid directories. These are dir's created by system and are hidden.
    continue;

    char dirCopy[strlen(dirname)+ strlen(name) + 1 /* for slash */  + 1 /*for null character*/];

    strcpy(dirCopy, dirname);        
    strcat(dirCopy, "/");
    strcat(dirCopy, name);

    struct stat s;

    if( stat(dirCopy, &s) == 0 )
    {
        if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
        {
            //              it's a directory
            //              printf("Directory [%s]\n", dirCopy);
            ScanDirectories(dirCopy, imagesHeadPtr, filesHeadPtr); //Already inside a dir, recursively traverse it.
        }
        else if( s.st_mode & S_IFREG )
        {
            //it's a file
            //printf("File [%s]\n", name);

            ++totalFiles;
        }
        else
        {
            //something else
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error
        return(0);
    }

    int extensionLength = 0;
    char *endP = name + strlen(name) - 1; //pointer to the last char of filename
    char *temp = endP;

    while (*temp != '.')
    {
        ++extensionLength;
        --temp;
    }

    char *extension = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(extensionLength+1 /* for . */ + 1 /* for null char */));
    strncpy(extension, name+strlen(name)-extensionLength-1, extensionLength+2);

    if(strcmp(extension, ".abc")==0)
    {                
        ++pngs;

        struct images *nextPtr = imagesHeadPtr;

        while(nextPtr->next != NULL)
        nextPtr = nextPtr ->next;

        nextPtr->fileName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(name)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->fileName, name);
        nextPtr->filePath = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(dirCopy)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->filePath, dirCopy);
        nextPtr->isUsed = 0;
        nextPtr->fileSize = GetFileSize(dirCopy)/1000.0;
        nextPtr->next = (struct images *)malloc(sizeof(struct images));
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        nextPtr->fileName = NULL;
        nextPtr->filePath = NULL;
        nextPtr->isUsed = 0;
        nextPtr->fileSize = 0;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;
    }

    else if(strcmp(extension, ".rst")==0)
    {                
        ++jpgs;

        struct images *nextPtr = imagesHeadPtr;

        while(nextPtr->next != NULL)
        nextPtr = nextPtr ->next;

        nextPtr->fileName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(name)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->fileName, name);
        nextPtr->filePath = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(dirCopy)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->filePath, dirCopy);
        nextPtr->isUsed = 0;
        nextPtr->fileSize = GetFileSize(dirCopy)/1000.0;
        nextPtr->next = (struct images *)malloc(sizeof(struct images));
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        nextPtr->fileName = NULL;
        nextPtr->filePath = NULL;
        nextPtr->isUsed = 0;
        nextPtr->fileSize = 0;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;
    }

    else if(strcmp(extension, ".dig") == 0)
    {
        ++filesToScan;

        struct filesToParse *nextPtr = filesHeadPtr;

        while(nextPtr->next != NULL)
        nextPtr = nextPtr ->next;

        nextPtr->filePath = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(dirCopy)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->filePath, dirCopy);
        nextPtr->next = (struct filesToParse *)malloc(sizeof(struct filesToParse));
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        nextPtr->filePath = NULL;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;        
    }

    else if(strcmp(extension, ".x") == 0)
    {
        ++filesToScan;

        struct filesToParse *nextPtr = filesHeadPtr;

        while(nextPtr->next != NULL)
        nextPtr = nextPtr ->next;

        nextPtr->filePath = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(dirCopy)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->filePath, dirCopy);
        nextPtr->next = (struct filesToParse *)malloc(sizeof(struct filesToParse));
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        nextPtr->filePath = NULL;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;        
    }

    else if(strcmp(extension, ".cderf") == 0)
    {
        ++filesToScan;

        struct filesToParse *nextPtr = filesHeadPtr;

        while(nextPtr->next != NULL)
        nextPtr = nextPtr ->next;

        nextPtr->filePath = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(dirCopy)+1));
        strcpy(nextPtr->filePath, dirCopy);
        nextPtr->next = (struct filesToParse *)malloc(sizeof(struct filesToParse));
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        nextPtr->filePath = NULL;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;                        
    } 

        free(extension); //because of this line, my code runs into infinite loop saying
//unable to open dir : too many files open. If I comment this out, my code works fine but the concepts of memory management say that I should be freeing it. 

}

free(tmp);

if (closedir(dir) != 0)
perror("Unable to close directory");

return(1);
```

}

Comment: Use debugger and check where exactly it is when in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C library function `strcmp()` stops comparing when strings differ or `\0` (end of string) is reached: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

```
if(strcmp(tmp, ".") == 0)   //Not valid directories. These are dir's created by system and are hidden.
    continue;
```

But tmp string doesn't have null terminator `\0`. So the comparison generates the infinite loop.

Reserve 2 bytes instead of one for tmp string:

```
char *tmp = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
```

Add the terminator `\0` to the string:

```
tmp[1]='\0';
```

Comment: I see there should be a null terminator there but why does it not happen when I comment out like this? //free(extension)

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks. This fixed the bug. Oh I am loving C.

Comment: there is a problem there also... try to declare the pointer outside the `while` loop, because you're doing it in every iterarion. Inside the iteration: `extension = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(extensionLength+nullCharLength));` Outside the iteration: `char *extension;`. What if the file has no extension?

Answer (score 3):

*UPDATE*: Adding another observation, for completeness' sake:

The `tmp` handling is also broken; it's allocated as a 1-character buffer, which can never hold any valid C string except the empty string, since 1 character is needed for the string termination character.

Remove `tmp`, and just compare against `ent->d_name` directly:

```
if(strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0)
  continue;
```

Then, this:

```
char *endP = name + strlen(name) - 1; //pointer to the last char of filename
char *temp = endP;

while (*temp != '.')
{
    ++extensionLength;
    --temp;
}
```

will break horribly for filenames that don't contain a period.

A more sane approach is to look for the last period, and handle the case of it not existing:

```
const char *ldot = strrchr(name, '.');
if(ldot != NULL)
{
  /* Extension found. */
}
else
{
  /* No extension. */
}
```

Of course, using library functions such as `strrchr()` on filenames isn't safe if the filenames are in a multi-byte encoding; you need to be aware of this.

Comment: In this case it should be `const char *extension = strrchr(name, '.');` and he should remove `malloc` and `strncpy`.

Comment: All filenames are  containing '.' Where is the leak in this? char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)); is outside the while loop and is freed in the end. I am not able to see where my memory management is going wrong?

Comment: but if you see the next line     strncpy(tmp, name, 1);
it copies only one char starting at address represented by name which is same as &name[0]. tmp should be of size 2 bytes 1 for '.' and one for '\0'. Isn't it?

Comment: char *endP = name + strlen(name) - 1; //pointer to the last char of filename
char *temp = endP;

while (*temp != '.')
{
    ++extensionLength;
    --temp;
} again why would this leak horribly??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all the code, but bug i probably here:

```
if(strcmp(tmp, ".") == 0)   //Not valid directories. These are dir's created by system and are hidden.
continue;
```

by using this construction you're only exclude . (current) directory. So you're not excluding .. (parent) directory, which causes loop. Besides you want to exclude hidden dirrectories, so best idea is to use this construction:

```
if (tmp[0] == '.')
```